# Rewrite ALL requests to a folder with .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite all requests in a folder like this:

**https://www.test.com/banana/apple** (or whatever) goes to **https://www.test.com/public** but in the url is still **https://www.test.com/banana/apple**.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Inside that specific folder** you can create a .htaccess with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /public/ [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

This `.htaccess` will rewrite all requests to `/public/index.php`. Existing files and directories will still be served.